# If a local file doesn't exist scp it from a remote machine and print message

Tags: bash, shell

All I want to do in a bash script is that if a given file doesn't exist in my local machine scp it from a remote machine and print message accordingly. I've read many related posts couldn't find a solution.

This will be convenient, and I tried but it doesn't seem to work with the &&.

```
  cmd=(echo "hello world")
```

This is the command I have:

```
  RESULTS_FILE="$TESTCASE_DIR"/"$FILENAME"_"$i".csv
  SCP_CMD="scp -2 ${HOST}:${REMOTE_TESTCASE_DIR}/${FILENAME}.csv ${RESULTS_FILE} 2>&1"

  if [ ! -f ${RESULTS_FILE} ] && [ eval $SCP_CMD ] ; then
      echo "Successfully scped the file";
  else 
      echo "SCP failed"
  fi
```

this fails with error `[: eval: unary operator expected`.
Backticks don't work either.

Comment: Remove the `[]` from the `eval`.  And your variable is `$SCP_CMD`, not `$CMD`.  That ought to work.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[ ]` are used for testing conditions. In your case, you don't need to test a condition on the `eval` side, you just need to execute the `eval` on true return of the left half of `&&` (the file doesn't exist).

So, this becomes as simple as removing the `[]` from the `eval` expression.

```
  RESULTS_FILE="$TESTCASE_DIR"/"$FILENAME"_"$i".csv
  SCP_CMD="scp -2 ${HOST}:${REMOTE_TESTCASE_DIR}/${FILENAME}.csv ${RESULTS_FILE} 2>&1"

  if [ ! -f ${RESULTS_FILE} ] && eval $SCP_CMD; then
      echo "Successfully scped the file";
  else 
      echo "SCP failed"
  fi
```

You ought to be able to do it without the `eval` in the first place. Just insert your command directly and it will be executed under the same conditions (non-existing file).

```
  RESULTS_FILE="$TESTCASE_DIR"/"$FILENAME"_"$i".csv

  if [ ! -f ${RESULTS_FILE} ] && scp -2 "${HOST}:${REMOTE_TESTCASE_DIR}/${FILENAME}.csv" ${RESULTS_FILE} 2>&1; then
      echo "Successfully scped the file";
  else 
      echo "SCP failed"
  fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can synchronize files from local machine with remote using [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) utility

```
rsync -avz ${HOST}:${REMOTE_TESTCASE_DIR} ${TESTCASE_DIR}
```

- a - archive, a quick way of saying you want recursion and want to preserve almost everything;
- v - verbose
- z - compress data during transfer

Example of rsync execution

```
$ rsync -avz Directory1/ Directory2/
sending incremental file list
./
file1.txt
file2.txt

sent 264 bytes  received 53 bytes  634.00 bytes/sec
total size is 94  speedup is 0.30
```